# How did `find` actually locate a character in a string, when it was passed a string, not a character?

Tags: red

I was surprised to note that `find "rspq" "q"` actually found q in the series. The reason it surprised me is that the string `"rpsq"` is a series of characters and I expected to have to specify `"q"` as a character not as a string.

This leads to 2 questions for me:
1. how do I specify the character `q` in Red?
1. why did the search succeed even though I passed in a string not a character?

Comment: You probably expected a functionality of `find`'s `/same` refinement. In documentation (`? find`) you can read: `/same        => Use "same?" as comparator.` But strangely, even with `find/same`, result is not what you would expect, despite that `(same? "q" "q") = false`.

Comment: Anyway, I think you should not ask two questions at once, and think about keeping your question's title reflect what you ask in the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Consult the [official reference documentation](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/datatypes/char.html).
2. Functions in Red are highly polymorphic. `find` can either search for a given element or a first occurence of sub-series.

Answer (score 2):

1. Characters are values of `char!` type, and are specified like this: `c: #"q"`.
2. I'd say it's because Red tries to copy behavior of Rebol. And in [Rebol's documentation](http://rebol.com/docs/words/wfind.html) you can find this example:

```
probe find "here and now" "and"
"and now"
```